Record Level Security of OpportunityHistory
I'm trying to figure out wether my Opportunity Trigger Handler should be without sharing or with sharing. The trigger operates only on Opportunities that the user has access to, but it is necessary that the trigger handler has access to every OpportunityHistory row for the corresponding Opportunity for it's calculation.
Can there be a case where certain Org-wide defaults, Role hierarchies, sharing rules, and manual sharing settings cause a user to have access to an Opportunity, but not every OpportunityHistory row for that opportunity?
Ways I have tried to cause a user to not have access to every OpportunityHistory row...

In the "Sharing Settings", I have no option to set OpportunityHistory rules.
When creating a "Sharing Rule", I can't create an OpportunityHistory sharing rule, just an Opportunity sharing rule.
I've tried certain Opportunity Sharing Settings, like Opportunity: StageNOT EQUAL TOValue Proposition. My thought process was if an Opportunity currently is Closed Won, but used to be Value Proposition, then the Value Proposition OpportunityHistory row would not show for a user. It DID show.

Can I trust that if a user has access to an opportunity, that all history rows will always show, and therefore make my trigger handler with sharing?

Users can't see history entries for fields they don't have access to. However, as long as they have current access to the record, they will have access to all entries for fields they can at least view.

Thank you, that makes sense. I am only using systemmodstamp from the OpportunityHistory table, and from my understanding, access to that field cannot be removed.

@louis Correct. Glad I was able to help.

I ended up changing it to 'without sharing' for a different reason. If Leads are set to 'Public Read/Write/Transfer', but Opportunities are set to 'Public Read Only', and a user converts a lead that they don't own into an opportunity, 'Without sharing' is necessary for the after-insert opportunity trigger
